# JavaScript - select the last item from the 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Let's say I have a simple HTML markup with three elements and a javascript loop looking through all of them. What I need to do is to select the last one of those items.

This pile of code will run a loop, select all elements with `some_div` class, and paste some text inside them...

What if I only wanted the last item on the list to be selected and changed?

Is there a way for me to only select the last item from the loop and then do some operations like adding a specific class to this exact element?

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some_div');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

    elements[i].innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```

```css
.some_div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry but it makes no sense to me... `elements[i] = elements[i].innerHTML` (if stored in a variable) will replace the value of that variable... with a value of this value... WHERE is the logic?

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I didn't mean to write an assignment operator. It was supposed to be: `var i = elements.length; elements[i].innerHTML = 'hello';`, although my count was still off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Selecting* the last match for a class (e.g., with a CSS selector) is awkward¹, but you can easily *access* the last match:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some_div');
var last = elements[elements.length - 1];
if (last) {
    last.innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some_div');
var last = elements[elements.length - 1];
if (last) {
    last.innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```

```css
.some_div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
 <div class="some_div"></div>
</body>
```

---

¹ *(or impossible? `:nth-last-of-type` applies to element type, not class...)*

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski - Right, but only if they're in the same container, and only if you don't need to qualify that with *anything* (not an element type, not a class, ...).

Comment: Well.. I nedded it mainly because I'm building a console for my text encryption tool and in order to leave the command line clean I had to figure out an idea how not to spam error logs if the user made a typo. Because of this I only display one log with a counter (just like in chrome/firefox console) The problem was to only change the value of the last log.
And now the thing is... Why did I start this project in the first place? I know a few tricks that will help me build an encryption tool in just JavaScript but I'm preatty sure I'll lose some nerves doing that...

Answer (score 2):

since `elements` is an array-like object, you can easily index the last item

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some_div');
if(elements.length > 0){
     const lastElement = elements[elements.length-1]
}
```

Comment: `elements` isn't an array, it's an `HTMLCollection`. But yes, you can access the last item that way (they just lack many other array features).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:
First things first, I start a counter which is going to count the elements.
Then, I call the tagName of the elements.
Next, I call for the parent element of the elements I'm trying to fetch.
If the the elements parentNode's ID is the one specified, code counts the elements.
I then turn the counter into a string and split the string into an array. [1,2,3]
Next I call for the last item of the array
I then concatenate the elements tagName and the last number of the counter, essentially becoming; for a random example: div[3].
And finally: do somthing with that element.

The only parts you need to change in the code is;
`el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")` 
change the text div to the elements you want' tagName.
 `if(el[i].parentNode.id == "parElement"){`
change the text parElement to the id of the elements parent element.
And of course, the last line; for what you want to do to the last element.

```js
function getLastItem(){
count="0";
el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
  for(i=0;i<el.length; i++){
     if(el[i].parentNode.id == "parElement"){
     ++count
     }
   }
    let arrayOfStrings = count.toString().split(' ');
    let lastItem = arrayOfStrings[arrayOfStrings.length - 1];
    el[lastItem].innerHTML="HI! I'm the last element!";
}
```

```html
To see it in action, run the snipper below 

<div id = "parElement">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="getLastItem()">Find Last Element</button>
```